# Passing parameters in callback URL Twitter API

Tags: twitter, callback

I have used OOB callbacks with desktop and mobile applications for twitter oAuth. But now I am moving onto the web based authentication for my web application consuming twitter api.

I have the following flow of events:

1. User fills a registration form(with say n fields+) entering his email id and twitter handle.
2. This generates the(short-lived)  twitter request token and the url for obtaining twitter Access Token and secret.
3. That url is sent to the user's email id, so that it serves the dual purpose of verifying the twitter handle and email id.

Now my question is:

Can I specify the callback URL with parameters so that when the user is redirected back to the application controller, the database receives the entries of the n form fields?

And also once the user is redirected back to the application, is it that the access token is appended to the callback URL (along with the parameters)? If yes, then how do I get the access token (token key and secret)?

To further clarify, consider the callback url:

http://www.someurl.com/controller?param1=val1&param2=val2

and on redirect to this url, I think(is it?) that twitter appends some params to this url, like 
http://www.someurl.com/controller?param1=val1&param2=val2&someParamsAppendedByTwitter=someValue

I just want to know what this `someParamsAppendedByTwitter` is/are.

The biggest issue with this question is that in almost all languages, twitter authentication is being dealt with some sort of plugins/libraries and there are very less resources on the same if you want to do it all by yourself.

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474097/sending-extra-parameters-to-twitters-oauth-authorize

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474097/sending-extra-parameters-to-twitters-oauth-authorize

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending extra parameters to twitter's oauth/authorize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474097/sending-extra-parameters-to-twitters-oauth-authorize)

Comment: This question was asked long ago and is not even relevant as twitter api has completely changed. @JoeMayo I don't know what to do about this.

Comment: @rahulserver - It might be good to delete it. When people look for questions with the [twitter] tag to answer, this shows up in the list as unanswered. Thanks.