# Sending extra parameters to twitter's oauth/authorize

Tags: twitter, oauth

I want to send some extra parameters to twitter's oauth/authorize endpoint (along with`oauth_token`) and get them back as it is in the callback request (along with `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier`). 
For example:

**request(extra parameter - `app_name`):**

https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=FxHxpekZK8VVfNRr38i2WKJskIZY3Hj7**&app_name=myTwitterApp**

**callback request should be(extra parameter returned as it is - `app_name`):**

http://www.example.com?oauth_token=FxHxpekZK8VVfNRr38i2WKJskIZY3Hj7&oauth_verifier=Vq0yq2LRUBybevnjGvXyUOBPWH9Ew9DY**&app_name=myTwitterApp**

Please let me know if this doable in twitter as it is in Google and Facebook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asked this question on twittercommunity and got the answer. The trick was to add the extra parameters in the callback url itself while obtaining the request token.

Comment: Can you update you answer with example of how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

Its not really obvious upon reading the [documentation here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/api-reference/request_token) !

You need to explicitly pass the "oauth_callback" query param containing the redirect url + any extra query params in your request token api !

```
const callbackUrl = encodeURIComponent(`${process.env.TWITTER_REDIRECT_URI}?ref=${ref}`)

const request_data = {
        url: `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=${callbackUrl}`,
        method: 'POST',
    }
```